# MYSQL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not updating when using INSERT OR REPLACE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I unable to update current time(`NOW`) in last_updated cloumn.

Because i have read this query from text file.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name (kb_corporate_guid,kb_user_guid,
                                   name,last_updated) 
VALUES ('100','121','FAQ','2013-02-07 07:06:05');
```

I want to `ignore last_updated` cloumn value '2013-02-07 07:06:05' even if i specified in query and `replace with NOW()` value into last_updated cloumn.

I tried this one but it won't work for me.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
   CHANGE `last_updated` `last_updated`  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

You may create trigger on insert/update which will update `last_updated` field with MySql `NOW()` function, it will overwrite the field value, but it might slow down the process when you do bulk insert/update.

**Option 2**

Find and Replace the text for last_updated field and timestamp values from text file.

**Option 3**

Create temporary table with same schema and import into temporary table then use `INSERT INTO main_table SELECT corp_id, user_id, name, NOW() FROM temp_table` table to insert into main table.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for ur reply ..., Is there a solution like this by using ALTER TABLE table_name
   CHANGE `last_updated` `last_updated`  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Comment: Yes you can have this if field's data-type is TIMESTAMP

Comment: what if the field is DateTime

Answer (score 1):

Default is used when the value is not sent in the query, use now in the query instead of timestamp..

Comment: Problem is me read query from text file which file created//export from client side.so i can't use now() in myquery.

Comment: If its a text file, write script to fetch it and then replace the timestamp with now(), should be a piece of cake..